# New multidomain store front displays maintenance mode - Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, store-view, maintenance, multidomain

I basically want to create a new store front in magento and have a different domain linking to it in magento using the same products.

I am using site1.co.uk etc just as an example.

I have created a new Store (site2) in magento and its own Store Front using the main stores root category.

I created an alias domain in Plesk Panel (site2.co.uk) pointing to the domain of the current magento site (site1.co.uk). I also tried a normal domain with its hosting root set to the same as the site1.co.uk root directory. The alias domain I set up in Plesk 12 has the "Redirect with the HTTP 301 code" setting diabled.

I then added the following to my main magentos .htaccess just above "RewriteEngine on"

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.**site2**\.co.uk MAGE_RUN_CODE=**site2**
SetEnvIf Host www\.**site2**\.co.uk MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^**site2**\.co.uk MAGE_RUN_CODE=**site2**
SetEnvIf Host ^**site2**\.co.uk MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

However when I visit the new websites URL it takes me to the maintenance page of the current site (keeping the new URL in the bar not forwarding to the main store) and I am stumpted as to why this is happenening.

Any help is greatly appreciated and if I have missed out any info let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure maintenance mode is shut off
2. Refresh your cache, you can do this from the CLI at your site root

   - rm -rf var/cache/*
   - php shell/cache.php --refresh all
3. There is a good reference for making new stores in a Magento Multi-Store setup

   - http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/cache-storage-management

*Sorry, I cannot ask for clarification on your questions, I do not have enough Rep, I also cannot cite more reference links because of rep*

Comment: Hi JoeyH thanks for the reply, there is no maintenance.flag and the main site is working fine. Tried flushing the cache to no avail and have followed that link before I came on here. Any other suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Can you double check what your website code is in manage stores? Make sure it matches your htaccess (MAGE_RUN_CODE)

Comment: I have checked the store and store front codes and tried both in the .htaccess with no luck!

Comment: Running out of options, but I would try and comment the following code in index.php and see if you can force it off:

if (!file_exists($mageFilename)) {
    if (is_dir('downloader')) {
        header("Location: downloader");
    } else {
        echo $mageFilename." was not found";
    }
    exit;
}

if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that in the .htaccess I posted above I had it set to "website" once I changed this to "store" it worked perfectly!